# I want to get data in wp Api using search keyword

Tags: wordpress, ionic-framework, wp-api

I want to get data in wpApi in url i am using search like this

```
https://www.digitemb.com/wp-json/wp/v2/posts?_embed&?filter[order]=DESC&filter[posts_per_page]=5&search=digitize&page=1
```

My Question is that How do i get posts data from specific categories. i don't want to get data of all categories i use this logic  to

```
   search(keyword,id){
           return this.http.get("https://www.digitemb.com/wp-json/wp/v2/posts?_embed&?filter[order]=DESC&filter[posts_per_page]=5&search=" + keyword + "&page="+id)
                        .map(data => data.json());
          }
```

but this data can get all categories i want specific categories posts !

Answer (score 0):

Use the ID of the category to get back all posts from that category.

```
http://www.example.com/wp-json/wp/v2/posts?categories=category-ID
```

List of available arguments - https://developer.wordpress.org/rest-api/reference/posts/#arguments